# Determine in a Maven Plugin whether Batch mode is active

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

When I write a Mojo, how can I determine whether I am currently in Batch Mode (i.e. the `-B` parameter was given on command line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to put this:

```
  @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", required = true, readonly = true)
  private MavenSession session;
```

If you have defined that in your mojo definition you can within your execute method going like this:

```
  if (session.getRequest().isInteractiveMode()) {
    //..
  } else {
    //..
  }
```

This will give you the information about using --batch-mode.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked out the source code of maven's archetype plugin (`generate` mojo to be precise):

They just inject the boolean value into the mojo:

```java
  /**
     * User settings used to check the interactiveMode.
     */
    @Parameter( property = "interactiveMode", defaultValue = "${settings.interactiveMode}", required = true )
    private Boolean interactiveMode;
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-archetype/blob/maven-archetype-3.2.1/maven-archetype-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archetype/mojos/CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java) and pay attention to how do they use it in the source code:

```java
  if ( interactiveMode.booleanValue() )
  {
        getLog().info( "Generating project in Interactive mode" );
  }
  else
  {
        getLog().info( "Generating project in Batch mode" );
  }
```

Comment: This setup will read the information from the settings file but not the current option from the command line... which might be overritten.